# PyCharm: Switch off popup windows during typing

Tags: pycharm

I am a beginning programmer in Python with PyCharm. During typing I meet pop-up labels that gets me angry. I went to Settings -> Editor -> General ->Appearance, switched off "Show hard wrap guide" and "Show indent guides", but problem still the same.
Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.s)

Comment: Disable the Show Parameter info option in Editor > General > Code Completion

Comment: @Ivan image link is not working

Comment: I'v found solution myself. It is to go to Editor -> General -> Code completion -> Switch off "Auto-display parameter info". Thanks!